# Use a standalone JAR file in a Grails web application

Tags: java, grails, web-applications, jar

I am working on building a web application that needs to use a standalone JAR file at its core. Essentially, I have an application module packaged as a JAR file that I can run successfully on the Command prompt using a command like: `java -jar myapp.jar` and can pass some additional parameters as needed (basically the file name to process). This JAR has some dependencies on other JAR files, which are placed in the libs folder located in the same folder as the `myapp.jar` file. All this is working fine as a standalone JAR file executed through the command prompt.

Now, I need to use this JAR inside a web application and do the same kind of processing. I have already got a Grails based web application setup with the required UI, etc. and I have added all the required JAR libs inside the `lib` folder of my Grails web application. I have placed `myapp.jar` file as well in the same lib folder.

I am a little confused about how to run this `myapp.jar` file through my web application's Controller methods? Basically, I have a form in my web application in which the users would specify the required file path needed to be processed by `myapp.jar` and then user would click the Run/Submit button. Upon that I need to launch `myapp.jar` with the supplied parameters of the file path and put the resulting/processed file at some specified location.

So, essentially do the processing similar to the standalone JAR execution on command prompt through the Web application's controller method.

Can someone kindly guide me regarding the right process to accomplish this?

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `MANIFEST.MF` in the `/META-INF/` directory within `myapp.jar` file you should find the `Main-Class` attribute.  If, for example, the main class is `com.example.MyApp` you should be able to call it's static main method from your code (i.e., from your Grails Controller method).

```
String[] args = new String[] { '/path/inputFile', '/path/outputFile' }
com.example.MyApp.main(args)
// do something with output file
```

If you have access to the source of `myapp.jar` you might be better off reviewing what `main` does and then just use the API directly.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me John. I'm trying out the first approach now and have a feeling that might serve my purpose. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the source of `myapp.jar` so won't be able to use the API directly.

Comment: John, so I was able to use the approach mentioned by you. But with some minor modifications. Using the syntax that you mentioned I was getting an error of the type: `Groovy:No expression for the array constructor call`. So, I modified the syntax and combined the two statements as: `com.example.MyApp.main(["inputFile"] as String[])`. This works fine now. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: John, if you don't mind, could you kindly take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855937/grails-jar-dependency-throws-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception-log4j-properties) as well? It's an extension of this question but is on a slightly different topic, so wanted to track it in a different conversation.